# Rebuild WiX when custom action binary changes?

Tags: msbuild, wix

I have a hand-crafted MSBuild script that build my WiX based installer. The installer contains a custom action DLL as a `<Binary>` element. MSBuild thinks the MSI is still up to date when this DLL changes, although it rebuilds correctly when I change other files that are part of components. Is there some way to tell the Light task to look at additional dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ProjectReference` from your `.wixproj` to your custom action project and MSBuild will correctly detect the dependency and should cause the installer project to build again. Additionally, WiX v3.6+ has improved the rebuild checks so ensure you are using a new version of the WiX toolset as well. If you still see problems it could be a bug in the WiX toolset that would be great to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using 3.7.

Comment: I am using v3.10 and this is still a bug. I make a change to a custom action and it is not reflected until I rebuild. This was very frustrating as I thought I was making a mistake.